# git remote -v output tags (fetch) and (push) for origin and upstream query

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to understand forking and contributing to project concepts. 
While doing this used the command git remote -v; post setting upstream.

I've couple of related queries

1) what is the meaning of parenthesis (fetch) and (push). The closet answer I got post googling is in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

2) if upstream has got both these flags, does it mean I can push to original repo without submitting PR ?

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram

some more info I got for this query. Editing question itself as this can't be added in comment section : "When you run git remote -v it shows you the list of repositories that you are tracking. 
These records always have two. One for push and one for fetch.

This is separate from your security permission.
When a fork is created, two remotes are added to this list. One is for the repository on GitHub.com and the other is for the repository that was forked (the parent) on GitHub.com.

The security permissions are handles differently and is only checked when a fetch or pull is made. If your permissions change at any time this is accounted for by doing the check when the actual push or fetch is performed.

Some more info on remotes can be found here:
http://gitref.org/remotes/"

Comment: From your link: `This means we can pull contributions from any of these users pretty easily. We may additionally have permission to push to one or more of these, though we can’t tell that here.` What do you mean by PR?

Comment: @Christoph `PR` is gitlab-lingo for their `pull-request` feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Every* remote defines two<sup>1</sup> URLs.  Let's look at their example:

   ```
   $ git remote -v
   origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (fetch)
   origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (push)
   [snip]
   $ git remote add pb https://github.com/paulboone/ticgit
   $ git remote -v
   origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (fetch)
   origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (push)
   pb  https://github.com/paulboone/ticgit (fetch)
   pb  https://github.com/paulboone/ticgit (push)
   ```

   At first, there was one remote, `origin`, which defined two URLs.  Then they added another remote, `pb`.  The act of adding (and creating) this new remote added two more URLs.

   The *fetch* URL is the one `git fetch` tries.

   The *push* URL is the one `git push` tries.

   In this particular case, as is very common, both URLs are the same—and in fact, you only have to list one URL, and it will automatically be used for both fetch and push.  If for some reason<sup>2</sup> you want to fetch from one place but push to another, you can simply set the two URLs to be different.
2. No, but it does not mean you cannot, either.  There's no connection between having multiple URLs and/or multiple remotes, and having *permission* to *use* those URLs.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually it's *at least* two, but except for really unusual cases, it's probably best to set *only* two.  Things get very confusing if you have more than two.

<sup>2</sup>For instance, suppose you work at a big company that has a number of fetch mirrors.  You're at a London location—not the New York office, not the Tokyo office, and not the San Jose office.  The SJ office has all the master (not-just-a-mirror) repositories, and is where `git push` must go, but there's no reason to go directly to San Jose for everything all the time.  It's much more efficient for all 50 London-office users to *fetch* from the London-office mirror.  So you point your system to fetch from london-server.bigcorp.com, not sj-server.bigcorp.com; but you set it up to push to sj-server.bigcorp.com.